# QML: Is it valid to put a Layout inside a Layout?

Tags: qt, qml

Will this QML code work?

```
Pane {
    ColumnLayout {
      RowLayout {
          ... stuff ...
      }
      RowLayout {
          ... more stuff ...
      }
   }
}
```

I am asking because ColumnLayout is not a container, so putting RowLayout (non-container item) into ColumnLayout (which is another non-container item) should not be a valid code. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Comment: Yep, you're wrong. `Container` is from QtQuick.Controls2. QML/QtQuick2 also works without QtQuick.Controls2, therefore `Container` is the least necessary `Item` for making QML/QtQuick2 work. Nesting `Item`s (*putting [...] into [...]*) on the otherhand is somewhat like the base principle for building UIs with QML/QtQuick2.

Comment: The simplest way to check for validity of code, is to run the code. Be brave. If the code is wrong, it won't break your hardware.

Comment: @dtech, not baseless assumptions. QT Docs say: "Positioner items are container items that manage the positions of items in a declarative user interface. Positioners behave in a similar way to the layout managers used with standard Qt widgets, except that they are also containers in their own right." . From this , you can deduce that non-positioner items are non-containers, when talking about Layouts. I suggest your to read the docs before commenting: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-layouts.html , I think you need to  improve your knowledge of Qt.

Answer (score 3):

Putting layouts inside layouts is the best way to create a complex layout.
According to to the [Qt Documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtquicklayouts-index.html) QML layouts are items and they can consequently be nested.

Comment: but this is QML, not QT Widgets, are you sure?

Comment: The linked documentation is about QML and clearly states: "Since layouts are items they can consequently be nested." so yeah - sure.