# Change width of items inside GridLayout

Tags: qt, qml

I am designing a simple high score in qml. I have decided to use a GridLayout inside a GroupBox for displaying some text. I dont know why, but I cannot change the width of the text. I have tried margins, but they also dont work. Right now the text crashes into the border of the GroupBox. (I want the GroupBox inside the Item because I'm going to add other things in it like a button later.)

```
Item {
    id: highscores
    width: 450

    GroupBox {
        id: highscore_box
        title: qsTr("GroupBox")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: 450

        background: Rectangle {
            y: highscore_box.topPadding - highscore_box.padding
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height - highscore_box.topPadding + highscore_box.padding
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "white"
            border.width: 5
            radius: 10
        }

        label: Rectangle {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottom: parent.top
            anchors.bottomMargin: -height/2
            color: "white"                  //set this to the background color
            width: parent.width * 0.6
            height: box_title.font.pixelSize
            Text {
                id: box_title
                text: qsTr("High Scores")
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                font.pixelSize: 32
                font.family: "Super Mario Bros."
            }
        }

        contentItem: GridLayout {
            id: highscore_grid
            columns: 3
            //width: ?????

            Text {text: "Place";font.bold: true; color: "white";
                font.family: "Super Mario Bros."; font.pixelSize: 30}
            Text {text: "Player";font.bold: true; color: "white";
                font.family: "Super Mario Bros."; font.pixelSize: 30}
            Text {text: "Time";font.bold: true; color: "white";
                font.family: "Super Mario Bros."; font.pixelSize: 30}
            Text {text: "1st";font.bold: true; color: "white";
                font.family: "Super Mario Bros."; font.pixelSize: 20}
            Text {text: "--";font.bold: true; color: "white";
                font.family: "Super Mario Bros."; font.pixelSize: 20}
            Text {text: "--";font.bold: true; color: "white";
                font.family: "Super Mario Bros."; font.pixelSize: 20}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with layouts, you can't use the standard anchor calls. You will instead need to [use these following calls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html) to manipulate your grid layout.

[image]

In addition, when you declare a layout, you need to specify what space it will occupy. You could use something like

```
anchors.fill: parent
```

Afterwards, you may need to also specify the space the objects inside of the gridlayout will take up. Yet again, don't use standard width/len calls but the Layout.XXXX calls.

Layouts are great for building fluid and dynamic screens, but they can be little rascals sometimes. [Nesting Layouts is extremely beneficial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479093/qml-is-it-valid-to-put-a-layout-inside-a-layout). I personally use many-many layers deep layouts. Gl!

I would recomend creating a 'practice' QML file wherein you create a gridlayout with many objects inside of it. Rectangles/buttons/more layouts. Get comfy with it. Once you have more understanding of layouts, then try and apply it to your existing problem which involves MVC.

Comment: Thank you, it worked using `anchors.fill: parent` on the GridLayout, then using `Layout.leftMargin` on every item that is on the left. But is there a way to add margin to the whole layout without putting it in the items?

Comment: Didn't need `anchors.fill: parent` actually.

Comment: Glad things seem to be getting better for you! You should be able to call Layout.leftMargin: on your gridlayout. Then all child items inside of the layout should have the margin applied. If that doesn't work. Keep your grid layout as the single margin location, then in each item you can call Layout.margins: parent.margin (I think).